# How to set button layout_gravity="fill_vertical" programmatically?

Tags: android, button, layout-gravity

I got a `GridLayout`, and two or more button inside, and all the buttons must with same width. My problem is that when the buttons having different line number of text, the `marginTop` of button will different too. How can I fix this? I want all the buttons in the same position of height.

Thanks.

I already try to set `Gravity` with `FILL_VERTICAL`, but not working.

```
GridLayout grid_neighbor = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.grid_neighbors);
grid_neighbor.setColumnCount(4);
for (i = 0; i < namelist.length; ++i) {
    Button temp = new Button(this);
    temp.setText(namelist[i]);                

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    lp.gravity = Gravity.FILL_VERTICAL;
    temp.setLayoutParams(lp);
    //temp.setGravity(Gravity.FILL_VERTICAL);
    temp.setWidth(button_size);
    temp.setHeight(button_size);
    grid_neighbor.addView(temp);
}
```

Here is the picture:

[image: My picture]

This is now working too.

```
GridLayout grid_neighbor = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.grid_neighbors);
grid_neighbor.setColumnCount(4);
for (i = 0; i < namelist.length; ++i) {
    Button temp = new Button(this);
    temp.setText(namelist[i]);                

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_TOP, temp.getId());
    temp.setLayoutParams(lp);
    //temp.setGravity(Gravity.FILL_VERTICAL);
    temp.setWidth(button_size);
    temp.setHeight(button_size);
    grid_neighbor.addView(temp);
}
```

This will work! Thanks.

```
GridLayout.Spec speccolumn = GridLayout.spec(i%4);
GridLayout.Spec specrow = GridLayout.spec(i/4, GridLayout.TOP);
grid_neighbor.addView(temp, new GridLayout.LayoutParams(specrow, speccolumn));
```

Comment: add rule align top with first button

Comment: Can't you set the button to have fill parent the height of its parent ?

Comment: @OMAK I try addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_TOP) & ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, both not working.

Comment: @Hardik4560 I set MATCH_PARENT is not working.

Comment: layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_TOP, button.getId());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set to the GridLayout row's baseline doesn't resolve your problem ? Because if you have different number of text lines in grid elements android will automatically try to align the text to the same baseline, not align the row elements.

Edit: I think it's more appropriate to set  rowSpec.alignment = TOP (Or one of the alignments available from http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.Alignment.html ). Please see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.LayoutParams.html for further reference.